# the typedef of pointer in c language

Tags: c, typedef

I have a question about typedef in c language.
I read the following code:

```
typedef void* (*RT) (int a, int b);
```

what is typedefed in this example?

Comment: This question gives you the info and links to be able to decipher yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89056/how-do-you-read-c-declarations  Teach a man to fish and all that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to use the good old "spiral method":

```
           +---------------------------------+
           |  +-------------------+          |
           |  |   +----+          |          |
           |  |   |    |          |          |
           V  V   V    |          |          |
 typedef void * ( * RT | ) (int a, int b);   |
              |   | |  |          ^          |
              |   | +--+          |          |
              |   +---------------+          |
              +------------------------------+
```

following the  line you can read:

- RT is ...
- a pointer to ...
- a function returning ...
- a pointer to ...
- void

You start from the type name and move alternatively right and then left (respecting the parenthesis as in the example).

Comment: Never heard of this, interesting.

Comment: Was published in an issue of the good old "Computer Language". Actually the "spiral" is an addition by myself but the concept is theirs. I found I remembered better this way.

Answer (score 4):

This is pointer to a function returning void and taking two int argument. The name of the type is `RT`.

When you are in such doubts, a very useful tool is [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/).

Answer (score 4):

```
        RT                  // RT
      (*RT)                 // is a pointer to
      (*RT) (               // a function
      (*RT) (int a, int b); // taking two ints and returning 
    * (*RT) (int a, int b); // a pointer to
void* (*RT) (int a, int b); // void
```

Answer (score 2):

See [**`cdecl`**](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void%2a%20%28%2aRT%29%28int,%20int%29):

```
declare RT as pointer to function (int, int) returning pointer to void
```

Answer (score 1):

`RT` is a pointer to a function that takes two integers as arguments and returns a `void *` (generic pointer).

Answer (score 1):

You are typedefing a function pointer. `RT` is the name of the typedef, `void*` its return type, and two times `int` are the argument types of the function.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration creates `RT` as a typedef name (synonym) for the type "pointer to function taking two `int` parameters and returning pointer to `void`".  You would then use `RT` to declare objects of that type, like so:

```
RT foo, bar;
```

as opposed to writing

```
void *(*foo)(int a, int b), *(*bar)(int a, int b);
```

or

```
void *(*foo)(int a, int b);
void *(*bar)(int a, int b);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a typedef for a function pointer to the name `RT`. This is often used for callback functions in libraries. So when a callback functions is required, the function signature can be more concisely written with `*RT` instead of the full signature.