# what does this statement in c means?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

```
struct abc
{
//some members
}arrayOf[10];
struct def
{
//some data memebers
}obj;

typedef void (*abc) (obj)
```

I am not sure what does the statement `typedef void (*abc) (obj)` implies. Please consider that I am new to this.

Comment: It's a function pointer. `abc` is a type that denotes pointer to a function returning void and taking obj as an argument. Google `C function pointers` for more detailed and correct description.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89056/how-do-you-read-c-declarations

Comment: That shouldn't compile. You're declaring `abc` as a pointer to a function returning nothing, and taking one argument of type `obj`, which isn't a type, so it should complain.

Comment: I'm also perplexed by the `struct abc` followed later by the `typedef abc` -- should this not also be a redeclaration error? Or do you get away with that because it's not a C++ compiler and the `struct abc` is distinguished from the `typedef abc` by the `struct` ??

Comment: @KScottPiel Struct tags live in a different namespace from ordinary identifiers, so that's no problem (and yes, it's because `struct abc {...}` only introduces a struct tag, and not a type name, as it would in C++).

Comment: I kinda thought so... still makes my eyes bleed. ~smile~ Bad programmer! No moon pie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it defines the type `abc` as a pointer to a function that accepts one argument of type `int` called `obj` and returns nothing (`void`).

Comment: Doesn't it strike you as weird that `obj` is not a type name here, though? I'm puzzled.

Comment: You are right - wonder if that would compile.  Perhaps there was supposed to be a typedef before the struct?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: What difference would it make? `obj` is still a variable name in this example, not a type name.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe if it were a type name, then it would mean the function pointer accepts a typdef of that struct as a parameter yes?  Or am I missing something really basic here?  See Lee's comment above...

Comment: Typedefs don't define new types: they give new names to types.

Comment: Fine, then the function pointer accepts a struct def type with the typedef.  :)

Comment: See Keith's answer, it's an implicit `int` argument and is old-style C

Comment: @MichaelDorgan : well yes..I think there must be a typedef before the struct , since there must be a type not a variable.

Answer (score 8):

Even ignoring the missing semicolon, it doesn't mean anything; it's an error.

If `obj` were a type name, it would define `abc` as an alias for the type `void (*)(obj)`, i.e., as a pointer to a function taking a single argument of type `obj` and returning `void`.

But since `obj` is an object name, not a type name, that's not actually what it means.

When I compile it with gcc, I get a warning:

```
warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
```

When I compile with `-pedantic-errors`, the warning becomes a fatal error.

An old-style (non-prototype) function *definition* can legally specify names, but not types, for arguments:

```
void old_style_func(obj)
/* obj is implicitly of type int */
{
}
```

But that form is not valid for a function *declaration*. In a declaration, a single identifier between the parentheses has to be a type name, not the name of a parameter -- which makes the declaration a prototype.

gcc's error message implies that it's trying to interpret it as if it were the beginning of an old-style definition, and then deciding that it's invalid because it's just a declaration.

The bottom line is that you should pay close attention to compiler warnings.

We could speculate about what was *intended*. Perhaps `obj` was meant to be a type name, and this:

```
struct def
{
    //some data memebers
}obj;
```

was supposed to be:

```
typedef struct def
{
    // some data members
} obj;
```

Or perhaps a type name was accidentally omitted, and the last line should have been:

```
typedef void (*abc) (struct def obj);
```

though in that case the name `obj` is being used twice for different purposes (legal, but confusing). But without more context, it's impossible to be sure how to "fix" it.

Where did this code come from? Are you *sure* you've shown us the exact code? What happened when you tried to compile it?

Comment: + seriously I surprised how next answer voted up that is actually wrong :O

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I'm not sure I've solved it. The code is incorrect; we still can't reliably guess what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

It introduces a new name `abc` for the type of a pointer to a function that takes an `obj` and returns `void`. The type of a pointer-to-function is always specified in this roundabout way in a declaration:

> *return-type* `(*` *name-being-declared*`)(`*parameter-list*`)`

Incidentally, the `*` in the declaration is probably unnecessary. Function types always magically turn into pointer-to-function types when you need them (like how an array type magically turns into a pointer-to-element type), and you can use a function type directly (instead of a pointer-to-function type) to declare a new function.

As others have pointed out, the context you give doesn't have a type named `obj`, only an object named `obj`. If this code compiles, there must be another type named `obj` defined somewhere else, in code you haven't given.