# Embedded Function Pointers

Tags: c, syntax, function-pointers

I'm having trouble understanding this specific declaration:

`void (*signal(int, void (*fp)(int)))(int);`

My previous understanding of function pointers was that the first item in brackets was the name of the function pointer.

eg
`int (*MySuperDuperNameForASimpleAddFunction)(int, int);`

I don't understand how it's possible to have anything other than identifiers in the first bracket.

Comment: Use the spiral rule or cdecl.org.

Comment: Related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89056/how-do-you-read-c-declarations

Comment: Interestingly enough, cdecl.org doesn't like the declaration.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen, It just doesn't like that `fp` is named. Try `void (*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void (*signal(int, void (*fp)(int)))(int);
```

`signal` is a function, taking :

- an int
- a function pointer taking an int and returning void

...and returning a function pointer taking an int and returning void. Phew.

Answer (score 2):

Standard rule: find the leftmost identifier, then work your way out remembering that function-call `()` and `[]` bind before `*`, so `*a[]` is an array of pointers, `(*a)[]` is a pointer to an array, `*f()` is a function returning a pointer, and `(*f)()` is a pointer to a function.  Apply this rule recursively for any function parameters.

With all that in mind, the declaration breaks down like so:

```
       signal                               -- signal
       signal(                    )         -- is a function taking
       signal(int,                )         --   an int parameter and
       signal(int,        fp      )         --   a parameter named fp of type
       signal(int,      (*fp)     )         --     pointer to
       signal(int,      (*fp)(   ))         --       function taking 
       signal(int,      (*fp)(int))         --         an int parameter
       signal(int, void (*fp)(int))         --         returning void
     (*signal(int, void (*fp)(int)))        --   returning a pointer to
     (*signal(int, void (*fp)(int)))(   )   --     a function taking
     (*signal(int, void (*fp)(int)))(int)   --       an int parameter
void (*signal(int, void (*fp)(int)))(int);  --       returning void
```

So, `signal` takes two arguments, one of which is a pointer to a function taking an int and returning void, and returns a pointer to a function of the same type as `fp`.

Answer (score 0):

The following was accepted by gcc:

```
static void (*signal(int, void (*fp)(int)))(int) ;

typedef void (sigfunc)(int) ;
static sigfunc* signal(int i, sigfunc* fp)
{
  fp(i) ;
  return fp ;
} ;
```

I have no idea why the return value from the `signal` function has to be wrapped around its definition in this way... and I suspect life is too short to allow me to discover !

I tried `static void (*fp)(int) signal(int, void (*fp)(int))` but the computer said **NO**.