# How does this example in standard section 6.8 works?

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

In standard Section §6.8 of the Standard (N3690 draft)  I see  this weird piece of code :

```
struct T2 { T2(int){ } };
int a, (*(*b)(T2))(int), c, d;
```

What is  `int(*(*b)(T2))(int)` ?!

Is `b` a pointer to `T2`'s constructor ?! or maybe a pointer to function pointer ?

It's weird that the bellow code also compile fine !:

```
struct T2 { T2(int){ } };
int((*b)(T2));
```

Comment: Use the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). `b` is a pointer to a function taking a `T2` and returning a pointer to a function taking `int` and returning `int`. Broader form of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89056/how-do-you-read-c-declarations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int (*(*b)(T2))(int)
```

It declares `b` as *pointer* to a function which:

- takes `T2` as argument
- and returns *pointer* to a function which

  - takes an `int` as argument
  - and returns an `int`.

One should simplify this declaration using typedefs as:

```
typedef int (*return_type) (int);
typedef return_type(*function_type) (T2);
```

Or better use C++11 style type aliases:

```
using return_type   = int(*)(int);
using function_type = return_type(*)(T2);
```

Then the declaration becomes this:

```
function_type b; //so simple!
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: And `int((*b)(T2));` is equal to  `int(*b)(T2);` ?

Comment: @omid: Yes. The extra parenthesis are superfluous. So you can write even this `int(((((*b)(T2)))))` which is same as `int(*b)(T2)`.

Answer (score 1):

It is declaration of variable `b`. `b` is a pointer to function with one parameter of type T2. The return type of this function is pointer to function with one parameter int returning int.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you understand what is going on here:

```
struct T2 { T2(int){ } };

typedef int (*func)(int);

int
(*foo(T2))(int) {
}

func
bar(T2) {
}

int main() {
    int (*(*b)(T2))(int);

    b = &foo;
    b = &bar;

    return 0;
}
```

So this is a function that take a T2 and return a function pointer to a function that return an int and take an int as parameter.

I a add this to my example of why c(++) is an horrible language.

By the way, you cannot take the address of a constructor (C++98 Standard 12.1/12 Constructors - "12.1-12 Constructors - "The address of a constructor shall not be taken.")