# Const Keyword Usage C++

Tags: c++, constants, keyword

I understand that the `const` keyword means that you can't change a variable's value so what does it mean if it used like this :

`const char* const& message`

Comment: that's a reference to a const pointer to a const char

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const?rq=1)? Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89056/how-do-you-read-c-declarations?lq=1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first const stays for the pointer reference itself cannot be changed, so you cannot do something like:

```
message = &something;
```

the second const is for the content of the pointer, so you cannot do something like:

```
*message = something;
```

Comment: ups. sorry.. i'll fix it

Comment: fixed it.. right now?