# Return block by function

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to know exactly, how to write a function that return block. Block syntax weird, as you know. The best solution i find, is following:

```
typedef void(^MyAwesomeBlock)(void);

MyAwesomeBlock blockFunction()
{
    MyAwesomeBlock block = ^{
        //some code;
    };

    return block;
}
```

Yeah, awesome, it work with typedef and it pretty neat, but, how to write correctly the same function without it?

I could put here a code that i tried, but i think that is no reason to do so, because it's just warn me with compiler errors all time.

Would you be so kind, to show me solution without `typedef`? Just a typical function, that return block. Thanks.

Trying following not work as well.
[image]

Comment: @robertvojta The other question asks about a *method*, while OP wants a *function*. It does not look like Objective-C provides a proper syntax for what OP wants to do.

Comment: @robertvojta i have seen that question, yes, but i still cant figure out how to do this with correct syntax..

Comment: @dasblinkenlight good catch, retracted my close vote ...

Comment: @robertvojta very nice one, and i agreed, without typedef those round brackets could make your brain melting..

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban it could, but it's not that hard. Several rules described in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/89100/581190) and this shouldn't be a big issue. But for the readability sake, stick with `typedef` :-)

Comment: @robertvojta yeah sure, but typedef is just kind of abstraction, its always good to know how things look under the hood ;)