# My pointers are causing "same type qualifier used more than once" warnings?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

From what I understood about using the const type qualifier with a pointer, is that it depends where you use it.

```
const MyType *
```

Would mean that the location cannot be modified, but the value at the location can.

```
MyType const *
```

Would mean that the location can be modified, but not the value at the location.

From this, I would seen no reason for the following not to be valid,

```
const MyType const *
```

To define a pointer whose location is fixed, and for which the value pointed to cannot be modified. However, this is throwing "same type qualifier used more than once." Should I ignore this? Is my understanding of const semantics in the context of pointers flawed?

Comment: How do you use the qualifier?  Can you provide a greater context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are slightly mistaken about the syntax. In fact

```
const MyType *
```

and

```
MyType const *
```

mean the same thing: the underlying `MyType` object is constant. The syntax for making the pointer itself constant is:

```
MyType * const
```

Thus if you want both to be constant, you would use:

```
MyType const * const
```

Or:

```
const MyType * const
```

A way to remember this is: the thing which is constant is the thing immediately to the left of the keyword `const` (which is `*` for pointer or `MyType` for the object), unless there is nothing to the left: in which case it is the thing to the right.

Comment: See [how do you read C declarations?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/89056/4892076) and the right hand clockwise rule

Comment: I had a feeling I must have been missing something. Thank you for the detailed yet concise clarification!

Answer (score 2):

`const MyType *` and `MyType const *` are the same thing. They both mean pointer to const, i.e. the pointee is const. So for `const MyType const *`, you'll get the error because the const qualifier is used twice for the same thing.

What you want might be `MyType const * const`(note the position of `const` and `*`), which is a const pointer to const, i.e. the pointer itself and the pointee are both const. You could read it from right to left as "const pointer to const `MyType`".