# Need help decoding this typedef

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, reference, typedef

I'm trying to create a reference to an array.
It works this way:

```
typedef int array_type[100];

int main() {
    int a[100];
    array_type &e = a;    // This works
}
```

But then I was trying to remove the `typedef`, and get the same thing working. Haven't been successful.

```
int main() {
    int a[100];
    // int[100] &e = a;    // (1) -> error: brackets are not allowed here; to declare an array, place the brackets after the name
    // int &e[100] = a;    // (2) -> error: 'e' declared as array of references of type 'int &'
}
```

What is wrong with my interpreation of `typedef`? And how could I remove the `typedef`, and still get the same functionality.

Comment: I recommend keeping the typedef - it hugely improves readability

Comment: I was trying to understand how typedefs work. And hence tried removing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add parentheses to tell that this is a reference to array, but not an array of something. e.g.

```
int (&e)[100] = a;
```

Or use [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) or [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) (both since C++11) to make it simpler.

```
auto& e = a;
decltype(a)& e = a;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But how could I have known that a bracket is to be placed around `(&e)` ?

Comment: @vishal Remember it. :) Well, if you write something like `int a[100];`, `a` will be considered as an array of 100 `int`s. If you write `int& a[100];`, `a` will be an array of 100 `int&`s (thus it's ill-formed). So you have to use parentheses to tell that it's not array, but a reference to array. It's same as pointer to array. e.g. if you want a pointer to array of 100 `int`s you have to write `int (*a)[100];`. BTW: Function pointers have similar issues.

Comment: @vishal : keep in mind that C types are [read from the inside out in a clockwise spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89056/how-do-you-read-c-declarations) : `e` is a reference (`&`) to and array of 100 (`[100]`) `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid this kind of confusion, it is actually a good opportunity to move to templated types, as there is `std::array`. Among other things, they provide the means to somewhat unify the syntaxes you need to use, and as in this example, remove the confusion of references/arrays/...

```
int main() 
{
    std::array<int, 100> a;
    std::array<int, 100>& e = a;
}
```

Nothing prevents you from still providing a type alias:

```
using array_type = std::array<int, 100>;
```