# What does the following declaration means?

Tags: c

I'm new to programming world and i'm studying about pointers and array. and i read this code on a website. what does this line of mean?

```
 int(*ptr)[10];
```

Is it a pointer or an array of size 10?

Comment: Both. It's a pointer to an array of size 10. And conversely `int* ptr[10]` would be an array (of size 10) of pointers.

Comment: Also abandon the site you are reading.

Comment: A handy website for some of this: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: ptr is a pointer to an array of 10 interger.

Comment: Removed the C++ tag since no-one in their right mind would use this :-) Also closed as dupe since there is a perfectly good canonical question on how to read C types.

Comment: These types of questions can be asked in interview.

Comment: [The ``Clockwise/Spiral Rule''](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a pointer to an array of 10 `int`.

Instead `int *ptr[10]` is an array of 10 `int` pointers.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/89100/5596981

Therefore it's a pointer to an array.

For another example, in `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, `argv` is an array of pointers.