# const char** vs const char* mutation

Tags: c, pointers, char

In my code I attempt to do the following things:

```
// Attempt #1
const char** strings;
strings[0] = "apple";
strings[1] = "orange";
strings[3] = "bananas";

// Attempt #2
const char* chars;
chars[0] = 'a'; // Error
chars[1] = 'b'; // Error again
```

When I compile GCC is fine with Attempt #1, but with Attempt #2 it says LHS must be assignable. Apparently by the virtue of `const` identifier the array chars is not assignable. Why?

Comment: Basically what you want is `const char* strings[N]` and `const char chars[N]` where `N` is the number of elements. Either that or you use `malloc` during runtime. In your second case you could do `const char chars[N] = { 'a', 'b' }` or just drop the `const`...

Comment: This would have been so much easier to understand had the standard *not* allowed prefix-const on the leading-most type (iow, mandate `const` be attached immediately after the type, not optionally before, but only for the outermost type).

Comment: @DeiDei for the sake of consistency and uniformity (and perhaps the nature of code itself) I am against using array brackets.  (Id rather do *(ptr +N) = value than ptr[N])

Comment: @Ace You're going to get real-tired of doing that someday, and by real-tired, I mean tired of the coworkers  maintaining your code asking you to decipher it because you're the only one on the team that  does it. Just fair warning.

Answer (score 2):

Read `const char**` as "a (non-const) pointer to a (non-const) pointer to a constant character". You're allowed to modify `strings` and `strings[n]`, but not `strings[n][m]`.

`const char*` is just one level in. You can modify `chars` but not `chars[n]`.

The way you'd make `strings[n]` non-modifiable is with `const char* const*` - "a (non-const) pointer to a *const* pointer to a constant character"

Also note that in your example `strings` and `chars` are not initialized. You'll need to initialize them before you can actually access them.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89056/how-do-you-read-c-declarations) has methods of how to read C declarations. In these simple cases you read right-to-left.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. So my intention is to make the array pointers in both cases immutable. I just want to change the values themselves that are contained in array[m] or perhaps array[n][m]. So then should we go for char* const chars; and char** const strings ?

Comment: Also I am not sure when you say the vars are not initialized. I believe that's exactly what I do right?

Comment: @Ace Neither are being initialized. You're performing *assignment*. Initialization doesn't just mean "set value". It is a language specific term, and means "establish value at the time of declaration". `int x; x = 5;` declares an uninitialized `int`, then assigned the value `5`. `int x = 5;` declares and initializes `x`.  I.e. `x` does not exist without determinate value in the subsequent code.

Comment: @WhozCraig Gotcha thx! These variables are tightly controlled within small inline functions. So chance of returning wild pointers (uninitialized) is rather small. But I take your point.

Comment: @Ace if you have `const char* chars;` you *must* assign `chars` to something (e.g. `chars = ...;` before you can do anything with `chars[0]` etc.

Comment: @Kevin ^^ Yah understood! That is taken care of. These vars are first made to point to malloc'd space for N elements before doing any assignment.

Comment: @WhozCraig I see your point now. These pointers are made to point to malloc'd location first before mutating that space. I just havent shown it in the code for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

`char *string` is a pointer to array of `char`'s. something like this :

```
             .----.   .----.   .----.
             | s  | - | a  | - | m  |
             .----.   .----.   .----.
               ^
               |
char *string --.
```

it's just like you have an array and an pointer to the array :

```c
char strArr[3];
char *ptrToStr = &strArr;
```

you can initialize an `char *` in various way :

```c
char *string;
scanf("%as", string);
/* if you don't allocate buffer for `*string`, and specify "a" in string format, 
then `scanf` will do it for you. this is GNU-only extension. */

char *string2;
string2 = (char *) malloc (BUFF_SIZE);
sprintf(string2, "%s" , "Ghasem Ramezani");

...
```

But `char **string` is an *pointer to pointer to `char` array*. something like this :

```
                     .----.   .----.   .----.
                     | s  | - | a  | - | 1  |
                     .----.   .----.   .----.
                       ^
                       |
   .->  char *string --.
   |                 .----.   .----.   .----.
   |                 | s  | - | a  | - | 2  |
   |                 .----.   .----.   .----.
   |                   ^
   |                   |
   .-> char *string2 --.
   |
   .-------------.
                 |
char **strArr ---.
```

for example of `char **`, did you remember `argv` argument in `main ()` ?. that's exactly is type of `char **`. let's see an example :

```c
/*1*/ #include <stdio.h>
/*2*/ int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
/*3*/   for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
/*4*/     puts(argv[i]);
/*5*/   return 0;
/*6*/ }
```

```sh
$> gcc -o output main.c
$> ./output ghasem ramezani
./output
ghasem
ramezani
$>
```

as you can see in line 2, we can write `char *[]` instead of `char **`. why ? because as me and @Kevin said :

> Read const char** as "a (non-const) pointer to a (non-const) pointer to a constant character".

- some good stuff about string in `c`:

  1. [A TUTORIAL ON POINTERS AND ARRAYS IN C](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~mikec/cs16/misc/ptrtut12/pointers.htm)
  2. [The GNU C Programming](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctut.pdf)
  3. [C Strings. (Array vs. Pointer)](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/)
  4. [Pointer - c++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)